# Problem with ports in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to link my api with my webapp but is doesn't seem to work.
I have this error

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /users/me from
>   localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED)
>   (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

When I try to sign in, it doesn't find the users.

Here is the contents of my *docker-compose.yml* file

```
 version: '3'
    services:
      api:
        build: ./web3-2019-api
        ports:
        - "8080:8080"
      webapp:
        build: ./web3-2019-webapp
        ports:
        - "3000:3000"
        links:
        - api
```

Comment: The error seems to suggest that the failure is from webapp trying to connect to api. Am guessing localhost:3000 is working fine but then the reference inside to try and get to api:8080 is whats failing. See Ponnusamy's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect via docker host `api:8080` instead of localhost.

If you connect via localhost from webapp it expects 8080 to be running in webapp docker, but api is another docker and you should connect via `api:8080`. Though both are running in same machine they are virtual machines and you should connect via respective docker name within docker network

Comment: This is correct. Also use networks instead of links as the feature will be deprecated.